# HTML5: Input with date type is too high

Tags: css, html

I have an `input` that displays too high in Chrome while in Firefox it looks normal:

**Chrome**
[image]

**Firefox**
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="Date de déprat"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

When I change the `input` `type` to `text` it works perfectly. So how do I fix this without hard coding the `input` `height`?

NB: I use the code in [this](https://github.com/JohnAlbin/normalize-scss/tree/master/sass) page for normalization

Comment: Inspect and check in chrome whether any other css applied for that input.. or share your sample demo url

Comment: It will be great if we can review your markup code with CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the input field in Chrome like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz2LZ.jpg (this is just an example, you should inspect your own html page)

Then see on the right within the Style Tab what CSS properties cause the height's problem such as: margin, height, line-height, padding...

Answer (score 0):

You can add in yor CSS rules like height, padding or wherever to a specific type of input in this case

input[type="date"]{
  ...
}